# Drools can't return map from static function

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to return a map from java static function which is called in drools.

My static function in java looks like this

```
public static Map getMyMap() {
    HashMap h = new HashMap();
    h.put(1,2);
    h.put(2,4);
    return h;
}
```

When I try to import this in drools like
`import function com.mypackage.utils.CommonUtils.getMyMap;`

I get the the exception as below which is unclear

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:279)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1391)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1172)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.getMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findStaticMethod(CompilationUnitScope.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findSingleStaticImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findSingleImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInImports(CompilationUnitScope.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:468)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:405)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:405)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:46)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:110)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:1334)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileRules(PackageBuilder.java:1058)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:972)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:964)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:455)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:431)
    at com.mypackage.main.DroolsTest.sslRule(DroolsTest.java:58)
    at com.mypackage.main.DroolsTest.executeDrools(DroolsTest.java:112)
    at com.mypackage.main.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:24)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.createNameEnvironmentAnswer(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:303)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:274)
    ... 40 more
```

I thought it might be the issue with generics, so I have removed it.
If I try to change the return type from Map to List, function will be imported without compilation issues and I can use it as well.

Anybody knows what might be going wrong?

Comment: What version of Drools are you using? I've seen issues with generics when using the Janino compiler, but it looks like you're using the default (Eclipse). Also I notice that you've declared `h` as a HashMap; do you still have an error if you declare it as a `Map`? eg. `Map h = new HashMap()`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am using drools version 6.0.1.Final. Yes, I still see issue when it's I change it to Map. Actually I don't have any rule as well in the drl file. Only imports.

Comment: Are you not facing any issues while returing maps. If yes, can you please tell me the version?

Comment: I always use the latest version (7.44+). Are you using the 6.x versions for a reason?

Comment: The numbers may need to be added as objects, e.g., Integer(4)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas   My org uses the same version. I tested in the latest version. It's working fine. May be I will think of upgrading the version. Thank you